# Setting up session using CAS

Tags: java, cas

I'm working on integrating CAS in a legacy Java application. It's looking promising at the moment but I'm a bit confused as to where to handle the 'on-login' logic. The app relies on certain session variables being set when the user logs in. How can I handle this in my application?

i.e. User A has logs into client app A and decides he wants to do something in client B.

Since he's authenticated in client A, he is automatically authenticated and logged into client B. Since he wasn't logged into client B before (i.e. this is a new session) some house-keeping tasks need to take place. I'm a bit confused as to how and where I can take care of these tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this (or at the least the way I approached it) would be within a filter that is run after the CAS has completed.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken, but our University uses CAS, and I think I understand a bit how it works.

Your legacy app will need to redirect the user to the CAS authentication, and the CAS will then automatically return the user to your application (as he is already authenticated), along with his token...

You can make this happen instead of the old login page of your app.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I have that working correctly. The issue is once the user logs in, I need to perform initial setup. CAS is running on separate server and is not intended to handle application-specific tasks. What I need is a method that get called on the client application when a successful login has occurred.